# 3 dots above first line while I write code in react in Visual Studio Code, it moves the code and its very annoying

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sorry if it's a simple thing - I really searched for an answer. When I'm coding react or JS in Visual Studio Code, while I'm writing a line with three dots appears/disappears (like saving or compiling but it's not) that moves me down and up the code...
I have tried to uninstall every extension but it doesn't fix it. It's really annoying and makes me write on the wrong line.
I uploaded a pic to show what I mean!

[image: PICTURE HERE!!!]

Comment: Does it offer any information if you hover over it or click it?

Comment: no information at all...

Comment: You might want to reinstall. I've never experienced this issue.

Comment: The only thing in that position for me is author information from version control. It does bounce once when I first open a file but it stops as soon as it has the data from Git

Comment: so, I will check again git extensions and if it doesn't fix I reinstall as see sharper said!

Comment: It is one of your extensions, you can run the `Bisect` command to help figure it out.

Comment: what is `heroes`

Comment: Just had this appear in mine too. There's a bug reported here ~ https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144248

Comment: Looks like the culprit is Gitlens. See https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/1742

Comment: really thanks! Yes that was the problem! I dont know if they already fix it, to get gitlens enabled again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try disabling GitLens, I believe the problem started after their latest update:

```
GitLens — Git supercharged
12.0.0 - 2022-02-28
```